# AMPScript to get AccessToken failing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httppost

I am using below AMPScript to retrieve access token for my subsequent REST calls but it is failing with "Bad Request"

```
%%[var @con,@body,@body1,@auth,@output,@response,@res,@callstatus ]%% 
%%[SET @auth="Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
SET @body="{"clientId":"xxxxx","clientSecret":"yyyyyyy"}"
HTTPPost("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken","application/json",@body,@callstatus) ]%% 
%%=v(@callstatus)=%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using single quotes for the string and double quotes in the json of your body-variable. Additionally I suggest using HTTPPost2 as you need to use the returned body afterwards.

```
%%[
    Var @body, @callstatus, @response
    Set @body = '{"clientId": "xxxxx", "clientSecret": "yyyyyyy"}'

    HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response)
]%% 

%%=v(@callstatus)=%%
%%=v(@response)=%%
```

In the subsequent requests you need to add another parameter containing "Authorization" and then another one containing "Bearer [YOUR TOKEN FROM RESPONSE]".

**Further reading:**

- [HTTPPost2(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httppost2/)
- [Get an Access Token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm)
- [requestToken Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm)

Comment: Hi Marcus, I am still getting the same error `Unable to generate preview
The function expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response)
Index: 6971
ListID: 0

An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost2 function call. See inner exception for details.
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.`

Comment: Did you try to send this request using curl command line tool or postman chrome extension for example? Just to verify the credentials definitely work.

Comment: Yes I copied these from my postman only .. so credentials positively work

Comment: Just another try: `HTTPPost2("https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response, "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")` additionally also try this for your body (single quotes for string and unescaped double quotes for json): `Set @body = '{"clientId": "xxxxx", "clientSecret": "yyyyyyy"}'`

Comment: Perfect !! The second part worked for me `Set @body = '{"clientId": "xxxxx", "clientSecret": "yyyyyyy"}'` Thanks much Markus! really appreciate

Comment: Great news, glad I could help! Please accept my updated answer so others can easily see this solved the problem.

Comment: I know this is late in teh game, but how do I get a clientId and clientSecret?

Comment: @DigitalMC You need to create a new installed package and get the credentials from there. In the past this was done in the [AppCenter](https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/#app-center), but now this can be done within the Marketing Cloud interface. See [Install Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm) and [API Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm) documentation pages for more information regarding this.