# Start Journey via API and Success to URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I have two questions, I just do not get ahead.

1. I have a cloud page in the marketing cloud that is called by an external form, after submitting the data. There we process the data via AmpScript. Now I need a journey to start when the cloud page is opened. Can someone tell me how this API call needs to look?
2. The form referring to the CloudPage requires to return a Success message. How do I build this?

Thx so much

Comment: If my answer helped, for the benefit of others please mark it as accepted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The API-Call to trigger an API-Event to start a Journey looks like this:

> Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
>   POST /interaction/v1/events
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

```json
{
    "ContactKey": "ID601",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"AcmeBank.AccountAccessed",
    "EstablishContactKey": true,
    "Data": {
        "accountNumber":"123456",
        "patronName":"John Smith"
    }
}
```

**Important:** You need to get an access token first, and pass it in the headers of your API-Call to the events-route. Information on how to obtain this token can be found [in this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/179283/36218).

When using `HTTPPost2` AMPscript function to send the request, you get a response status code. Checking this code using an if-statement enables you to react to that status and display a success message.

```
%%[
    Var @body, @callstatus, @response
    /* add your desired request-body to this variable */
    Set @body = '{"ContactKey": "YourKey"}'

    HTTPPost2("https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response)

    IF @callstatus == 200 THEN
]%%

<p>Success!</p>

%%[
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [POST /interaction/v1/events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm)
- [HTTPPost2](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/httppost2/)
- [Get an Access Token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm)