# How to Generate Access Token Using Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript

Updating my question with new error code.
I tried the below code to generate Access Token. But I am keep getting an error.

> orted_grant_type","error {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Use \"authorization_code\" or \"refresh_token\" or \"client_credentials\" or \"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer\" as the grant_type.","error_uri":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"} System.Data.DataRow[]

Here is the code

```
%%[
VAR @httppost,@apiid,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse,@apitoken
SET @apiid = '{"clientId": "sxkyh9r","clientSecret": "v3Vqp7Hw1c"}'
SET @httppost = HTTPPost2("https://mcy070q4tjg2m.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token","application/json",@apiid,false,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse)
SET @apitoken = Substring(@apistatusCode,17,24)
]%%

%%=v(@apitoken)=%%
%%=v(@apistatusCode)=%%
%%=v(@apiresponse)=%%
```

I have created an app, where Integration Type is Server-to-Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AMPScript to get AccessToken failing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179277/ampscript-to-get-accesstoken-failing)

Comment: It is likely that you need to use the v2 Auth endpoint, but I just wanted to make a note that its `https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token` as I believe Adam accidentally added an extra `/v2` to the URL.

Comment: Just updated my question with new Error code....

Answer (score 3):

You need to include grat type in your payload:

```
SET @apiid = 
'{"clientId": "sxkyh9r","clientSecret": "v3Vqp7Hw1c","grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
```

Those three parameters are mandatory.
Additional two, which are not required, are MID and scope. Here's the reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm

It would be much easier, if you did this using SSJS - it would allow you to parse the JSON response correctly. An example [here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/27/salesforce-marketing-cloud-api-authentication-using-server-side-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

So it finally worked. Not sure if someone noticed or not but ClientID and ClientSecret should have been like client_id and client_secret.

```
%%[
VAR @httppost,@apiid,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse,@apitoken
SET @apiid = '{"client_id": "sx","client_secret": "vc", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
SET @httppost = HTTPPost2("https://mcjv.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token","application/json",@apiid,false,@apistatusCode,@apiresponse)
SET @apitoken = Substring(@apistatusCode,17,24)
]%%

%%=v(@apitoken)=%%
%%=v(@apistatusCode)=%%
%%=v(@apiresponse)=%%
```

But thanks to everyone for helping me out. As I newbie in API / JSON and SOAP REST.