# Can Marketing Cloud generate JWT tokens in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, jwt

As the title suggests, I need to make a callout to an external service but must sign the request with a JWT token (using a private key).

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Generate Access Token Using Ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280354/how-to-generate-access-token-using-ampscript)

Comment: No, this is to authenticate with MC API, whereas what I am asking is whether its possible to generate a JWT token in Marketing Cloud (for external apps)

Comment: Perhaps with the [SHA256](https://ampscript.guide/sha256/) function in a CloudPage.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Am I right to assume SHA256 doesn't support private keys? I don't see any parameters to support this.

Comment: I don' think it does.  You can upload keys for use with the [EncryptSymmetric](https://ampscript.guide/encryptsymmetric/) and [DecryptSymmetric](https://ampscript.guide/decryptsymmetric/) functions, but I'm not sure if that'll work for to generate a JWT key.

Comment: I think there needs to be a function to actually generate a JWT token, it doesn't look like MC has a AMPScript or SSJS function for this from my research :(

Comment: From what I can tell, it's not a binary file, so a CloudPage could just return a properly formatted output string in response.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Do you have an example of how this would work? (or any more details on how I could do this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113005/discussion-between-adam-spriggs-and-deployment-failure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is newly supported with the [GetJWT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/GetJWT.html) function.

```
string GetJWT(string key, string algorithm, string jsonPayload)
```

Example:

```
SET @JWT = GetJWT("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef", "HS256", @JSON)
SET @HREF = CONCAT("https://someurl?sign=",@JWT)
```